# Parsing through JSON values from STDIN

Tags: python, json, parsing

Is there a feature in the python json library that can parse individual json values from standard input into a json object?

For example, if the following is given in std.input:

```
"hello" "world" [1,
      2]     "coding"
 "python"
```

I want to be able to get a hold of each individual value and append it to a dictionary. There should be five values total in this example, as [1,2] counts as one value.

Comment: This is not valid JSON. Also, `json.loads()` doesn't care where data comes from, assuming it gets valid input. And why  a dictionary instead of a list? What are the keys for those values to build a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you might want to take a look at [`json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode).

For example,

```py
import json

decoder = json.JSONDecoder()

s = '''"hello" "world" [1,
      2]     "coding"
"python"'''

l = []
while s:
    obj, pos = decoder.raw_decode(s)
    l.append(obj)
    s = s[pos:].strip()

print(l)
```

gives me the output

```py
['hello', 'world', [1, 2], 'coding', 'python']
```

(I'm not sure what you meant with a dictionary - putting everything into a list seems to make more sense.)

If you want to get JSON objects while things are still written to stdin, you might have to occasionally try to run `decoder.raw_decode` to check if a complete object has already been entered. I'm not aware of a better solution with the standard library.

Also note that this might be rather inefficient for huge strings.